# Avoid duplicate styles in Angular Material theme

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, theming

I have a `styles.theme.scss` that looks like the following.

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  @include example-theme($dark-theme);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  @include example-theme($light-theme);
}

[data-theme="dark-theme"] {
  @include example-theme($dark-theme);
}

[data-theme="light-theme"] {
  @include example-theme($light-theme);
}
```

The goal is to use the [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) if that is configured by the user agent, but override it if the user has configured it on the website.

The current SCSS causes the following warning, however:

```
WARNING: The same color styles are generated multiple times. Read more about how style duplication can be avoided in a dedicated guide. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/duplicate-theming-styles.md
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 1648:7  -mat-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 7010:3  angular-material-theme()
    stdin 29:3                                           example-theme()
    stdin 57:3                                           root stylesheet
```

I've checked the provided documentation, but it doesn't appear to cover this case, and I'm unsure on how to better structure this to avoid duplicating the styles.

The only solution I think would work is to detect the preference with JavaScript, and then set the `data-theme` attribute if a theme isn't configured in the application.

Is there a better solution than this?

What I've tried:

- To see if I could string a media query and selector together like `[data-theme="dark-theme"], @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`, which I don't believe is possible.
- If I can use SASS `@if` and `@else` to check if the `data-theme` selectors match any elements, else include the `@media` queries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should include `mat.all-component-colors` instead of `mat.all-component-themes`

Example: below is wrong

```
// Generates styles for all systems configured in the theme. In this case, color styles
// and default density styles are generated. Density is in themes by default.
@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);

.dark-theme {
  // Generates styles for all systems configured in the theme. In this case, color styles
  // and the default density styles are generated. **Note** that this is a problem because it
  // means that density styles are generated *again*, even though only the color should change.
  @include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);
}
```

Use this instead:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

...
@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);

.dark-theme {
  // This mixin only generates the color styles now.
  @include mat.all-component-colors($dark-theme);
}
```

For more information, [Official Docs](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/duplicate-theming-styles.md)

Answer (score 2):

I also find my self fighting same issue today.
The problem with your styling is you have two theme light and dark and in

```
@include angular-material-theme('Your-Theme');
```

you have to provide a theme ( light or dark).

so you should overwrite only one of theme because other is already included
so overwrite media query dark if you provided light one or vice versa.

here is my code sample

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@include mat-core();

$kyc-web-primary: mat-palette($mat-pink);
$kyc-web-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$kyc-web-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$kyc-web-theme-light: mat-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $kyc-web-primary,
      accent: $kyc-web-accent,
      warn: $kyc-web-warn,
    ),
  )
);

$kyc-web-theme-dark: mat-dark-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $kyc-web-primary,
      accent: $kyc-web-accent,
      warn: $kyc-web-warn,
    ),
  )
);

@include angular-material-theme($kyc-web-theme-dark);


@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  @include angular-material-color($kyc-web-theme-light);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mat.$theme-ignore-duplication-warnings: true;

Comment: This is the correct answer, if you intend to have multiple themes (e.g. light and dark) inside the app. See: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/duplicate-theming-styles.md

Comment: What's the .scss equivalent to this? I get error: "identifier expectedscss(css-identifierexpected)"

Comment: @AppDreamer I'm getting exactly the same error, would like to know the solution to this...

Answer (score -1):

If you use scss you can use this : `$mat-theme-ignore-duplication-warnings: true;` to avoid warning if you intend to have multiple themes